# Perform operation on 2 aggregated fields in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

I'm trying to show four columns in the query below: a count of total responses, a count of incorrect responses, and a `%` incorrect based off the two previous columns. The results will be grouped by the `question_id`.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(correct) as total_resp,
    SUM(case when correct = 'f' then 1 else 0 end) as incor_resp,
    (incor_resp / total_resp) as percent_incor,
    question_id
FROM answers
WHERE student_id IN (
    SELECT id FROM students
    WHERE lang = 'es'
    LIMIT 50
)
GROUP BY question_id;
```

My question is, why doesn't the `percent_incor` definition in the above work? Do I not have access to `total_resp` and `incor_resp` to be able to perform operations off them for a 3rd field definition? If not, how would I be able to include this field in my output?

Thanks!

Comment: what you mean doesnt work? do you get an error or a wrong value? and why you use `LIMIT 50` without an `order by` that doesnt look deterministic.

Comment: Yup, this is the error I get:
ERROR:  column "incor_resp" does not exist
LINE 4:     (incor_resp / total_resp) as percent_incor,

Comment: Show your expected and actual output in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to refer to other fields via their aliases in the same select. Either you need to repeat the expressions again or you can wrap the select in another select and compute it there:

```
SELECT total_resp, incor_resp, incor_resp/total_resp as percent_incor
FROM (
    SELECT 
        COUNT(correct) as total_resp,
        SUM(case when correct = 'f' then 1 else 0 end) as incor_resp,
        (incor_resp / total_resp) as percent_incor,
        question_id
    FROM answers
    WHERE student_id IN (
        SELECT id FROM students
        WHERE lang = 'es'
        LIMIT 50
    )
    GROUP BY question_id
) t;
```

Comment: Thanks! Good to know

Answer (score 0):

you cant refer to the alias of a field the way you are within the `SELECT`.

try this:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(correct) as total_resp,
    SUM(case when correct = 'f' then 1 else 0 end) as incor_resp,
    (SUM(case when correct = 'f' then 1 else 0 end)  / COUNT(correct)) as percent_incor,
    question_id
FROM answers
WHERE student_id IN (
    SELECT id FROM students
    WHERE lang = 'es'
    LIMIT 50
)
GROUP BY question_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this code what you're looking for?

```
SELECT 
COUNT(correct) as total_resp,
SUM(case when correct = 'f' then 1 else 0 end) as incor_resp,
(SUM(case when correct = 'f' then 1 else 0 end) / COUNT(correct)) as percent_incor,
question_id
FROM answers
WHERE student_id IN (
SELECT id FROM students
WHERE lang = 'es'
LIMIT 50
GROUP BY question_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want use the alias you have to access a sub query

```
SELECT total_resp, incor_resp, total_resp / incor_resp as percent_incor
FROM (
        SELECT 
                COUNT(correct) as total_resp,
                SUM(case when correct = 'f' then 1 else 0 end) as incor_resp,
                question_id
            FROM answers
            WHERE student_id IN (
                SELECT id FROM students
                WHERE lang = 'es'
                LIMIT 50
            )
            GROUP BY question_id
        ) T
```

Answer (score 0):

Coudl be a problem with the case sintax

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(correct) as total_resp,
   SUM(case correct when 'f' then 1 else 0 end) as incor_resp,
   (incor_resp / total_resp) as percent_incor,
    question_id
FROM answers
WHERE student_id IN (
   SELECT id FROM students
   WHERE lang = 'es'
   LIMIT 50
)
GROUP BY question_id;
```